# Dart/Flutter How to initialize a List inside a Map?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I initialize a list inside a map?

```
Map<String,Map<int,List<String>>> myMapList = Map();
```

I get an error :

```
The method '[]' was called on null.
I/flutter (16433): Receiver: null
I/flutter (16433): Tried calling: [](9)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By just adding the elements when you create the map, or later by `add`ing them. For example:

```
var myMapList = <String, Map<int, List<String>>>{
  'someKey': <int, List<String>>{
    0: <String>['foo', 'bar'],
  },
};
```

or

```
var m2 = <String, Map<int, List<String>>>{}; // empty map
m2['otherKey'] = <int, List<String>>{}; // add an empty map at the top level
m2['otherKey'][2] = <String>[]; // and an empty list to that map
m2['otherKey'][2].add('baz'); // and a value to that list
print(m2);
```

prints `{otherKey: {2: [baz]}}`

Comment: eg. for a list of string is List<String> listString = [ ]; for map of string is Map<int , String> = Map( ); Is there a way to initialize the below statement without providing values eg. Map<String,Map<int,List<String>>> myMapList = ? ? ?

Comment: That syntax is very "Darty". Prefer `var listString = <String>[];` or `var someMap = <int, String>{}`. Move the type to the right hand side and let the analyzer work out the type of the left hand side.

Comment: Can I do something like: ```m2['otherKey'][2] = List<String>()``` and then ```m2['otherKey'][2].add('baz');```

Comment: `List<String>()` is the same as `<String>[]`, but the latter is the preferred syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Try initializing using `{}`

```
Map<String,Map<int,List<String>>> myMapList = {}; // just add {}
```

it will create an empty map and works perfectly fine.

Answer (score -1):

In case for list of int as value

```js
void main() {
  List<int> dividends = [99,101,176,182];
  Map map = new Map<int, List<int>>();
  
  dividends.forEach((i) {
    if(i > 0) {
      map[i] = <int>[];
      for(int j=1; j <= i;j++) {
        if(i%j == 0) {
          map[i].add(j);
        }
      }
      // print('$i, $map[$i]');
    }
  });
  print(map);
}
```